# unknown c++ object instantiation syntax

Tags: c++, opencv, instantiation, copy-constructor

I'm in the process of looking over the OpenCV tutorial on Cascade Classifiers, and happened to see this syntax:

```
std::vector<Rect> faces;
Mat frame_gray;     
Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );,
```

where there's some other code in between the frame_gray instantiation and the faceROI instantiation. My question is - what is the faceROI instantiation line doing/how does it work? It looks like a copy constructor usage, but the faces[i] parameter is confusing me.

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html - Tutorial
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#af1d014cecd1510cdf580bf2ed7e5aafc - docs for Mat class

Comment: Maybe the `Mat` class implements `operator()` and lets you call its instances as if they were functions...

Comment: According to linked documentation, it calls `Mat::operator() (const Rect &roi) const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That line is calling the

```
Mat operator()(const Rect &)
```

and not a copy constructor. This operator is used to call an object like a function.

You can find the information about this operator here:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a07413f2e3e63a12185b8b218c24c7270

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea that () could be overridden!